# Strlen returns actual length+2

Tags: c

Why does `strlen` return 6 instead of 4 even though the file contains a 4-letter word without spaces after the word?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void leggi_file(FILE *in, char *s);
char * vect(char *s);
int pal(char *);

int main(void){
    FILE *in;
    char *s[100], *v;
    int n;
    in = fopen("testfile", "r");
    leggi_file(in,*s);
    printf("%s",*s);
    v = vect(*s);
    printf("%s",v);
    n = pal(*s);
    printf("%d",n);
    int dim = strlen(*s);
    printf("%d",dim);
    return 0;
}

void leggi_file(FILE *in, char *s){
    int c, count = 0;
    while((c=getc(in))!=EOF && count < 100){
        s[count] = c;
        count++;
    }
}

char * vect(char *s){
    char *vect;
    int dim = strlen(s);
    vect = malloc((dim+1)*sizeof(char));
    vect = s;
    return vect;
}

int pal(char *s){
    int i, tmp, dim;
    dim = strlen(s);
    tmp=dim-1;
    for(i=0; i<(dim/2); i++){
        if(*(s+i) != *(s+tmp))
            return 0;
        else
            tmp--;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

testifile contains "anna"

Comment: `*s` is a pointer. Where does it point to?

Comment: Enable compiler warnings, then read them. I'm guessing you intended to use `char s[100]` instead.

Comment: What is in your file? Note: also count `\r` and `\n`.

Comment: Arrays decays to pointers to their first element, that is plain `s` is equal to `&s[0]`. When you do `*s` you're dereferencing that pointer, and get `s[0]`. Which is a pointer that haven't been initialized.

Comment: is there a reason you're using `char *s[100]` and not `char s[100]` ?

Comment: There are also many other problems in your code, the most notable being `vect = malloc(...)` followed by `vect = s` which discard the previous value of `vect`. After the assignment `vect = s` then *both* `vect` and `s` are pointing to the same memory.

Comment: In `main()` replace *all* `*s` by `s`.

Comment: What's the content of `testfile`? Please show a minimal `testfile` and the expected output. In addition to the other comments: `vect = s` should probably be `strcpy(vect, s)`. Read the chapter dealing with strings in your C text book.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I'm on ubuntu

Comment: Ciao, I also advise you to start using gdb (gnome debugger) to troubleshoot your code. In any case you don't put the line terminator `'\0'` when you read the line. Also I don't understand why you use a matrix for your data (char *[] equals to `char[][]`). Also check your file's last characters : those may be 'blanks' but getting counted anyway .> `'\n'`, `' '`, `'\r'` are all printable caracters not representing a gliph.

Comment: @DDS if you're referring to the ubuntu debugger i'm already using it. I don't understand how \r could be a problem since the file contains only characters.

Comment: `'\r'` IS a (printable) character: carriage return. If your file was saved for windows it's part of windows CRLF new line, if file was created on (old) macos it's the new line character.... ERROR gdb is actually GNU debugger (not Gnome as i erroneusly stated before)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want this. Explanation is in the comments. There is still room for further improvement though.

I'm not sure what the purpose of calling `vect` is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void leggi_file(FILE *in, char *s);
char *vect(char *s);
int pal(char *);

int main(void) {
  FILE *in;
  char s[100], *v;   // just use s, you want an array of char, not an array of
  int n;             //  pointers to char
  in = fopen("data.txt", "r");
  if (in == NULL)  // check if file could actually be opened
  {
    printf("Can't open file\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  leggi_file(in, s);
  fclose(in);       // close file
  printf("%s", s);
  v = vect(s);
  printf("%s", v);
  n = pal(s);
  printf("%d", n);
  int dim = strlen(s);
  printf("%d", dim);
  free(v);           // free memory
  return 0;
}

void leggi_file(FILE *in, char *s) {
  int c, count = 0;
  while ((c = getc(in)) != EOF && count < 100) {
    if (c == '\n')  // stop on first end of line
      break;
    s[count] = c;
    count++;
  }

  s[count] = 0;   // put string terminator, omitting this
}                 // was one of the major problems in your code

char * vect(char *s) {
  char *vect;
  int dim = strlen(s);
  vect = malloc((dim + 1) * sizeof(char));
  strcpy(vect, s);    // copy string
  return vect;
}

int pal(char *s) {
  int i, tmp, dim;
  dim = strlen(s);
  tmp = dim - 1;
  for (i = 0; i < (dim / 2); i++) {
    if (*(s + i) != *(s + tmp))
      return 0;
    else
      tmp--;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Also `(*(s + i) != *(s + tmp))` is more readable if yo write (`s[i] != s[tmp])` which is fully equivalent.

Comment: why do you break the loop when you encounter "\n"?

Comment: @user10967362 like this only the first line of the file will be considered. Depending on your requirement, you may want to remove that test. You should also tell us what _exactly_ the program is supposed to do.

Comment: Yeah but if I have a file with multiple lines then there is a problem. So maybe it's better to replace "break" with "continue", I guess?

Comment: @user10967362 well it depends on what the program is supposed to do, tell us more.

Comment: why doesn't the program work with >= 8 letter-words?

Comment: @user10967362 it works fine here. Please be more specific: which word exacly doesn't work?

Comment: altalena for example. It writes altalenaGenu when I run the program.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with the program above. You should learn how to use your debugger.